# Conditional MySQL Column

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, datagridview

Table: qa_selltypes

```
selltype_code, selltype_name
'1', 'unit'
'2', 'pound'
'3', 'box'
'4', 'gallon'
```

Table: qa_items

```
item_code, item_name, selltype_code, item_price
'1', 'PS2 Keyboard', '1', '10.45'
'2', 'Screws', '3', '15.02'
'3', 'Oil', '2', '30.00'
```

I need to refill a grid that contains four fields (unit, stall, pound, gallon) establishing item_price according to the relation to the field of selltype_code, one example: The rest set them to 0

DGV:

```
item_code, item_name, unit, box, pound, gallon
'1', 'PS2 Keyboard', '10.45', '0', '0', '0'
'2', 'Screws', '0', '0', '15.02', '0'
'3', 'Oil', '0', '30.00', '0', '0'
```

Comment: Use CASE statements, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select i.item_code, i.item_name, 
    case when q.selltype_name = 'unit' then i.item_price else 0 end as unit,
    case when q.selltype_name = 'box' then i.item_price else 0 end as box,
    case when q.selltype_name = 'pound' then i.item_price else 0 end as pound,
    case when q.selltype_name = 'gallon' then i.item_price else 0 end as gallon
from qa_items i
inner join qa_selltypes q on i.selltype_code = q.selltype_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case`. Example:

```
select case when some_column = 'abc'
            then 'hello'
            else 'good bye'
            end as conditional_column
from your_table
```